# Android JSONException "no value for key"

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection

I am a getting a JSON object from a website like this:

`JSONObject response = new JSONObject(read(placeConnection));`

and when I execute `response.toString();` I get the entire String for that JSON object and the key and value that I want is in there.

However, when I execute `response.getString("countryName")` I get the above exception and it says there is no value for that key.

Here is the JSON in String form:

`{"geonames":[{"countryId":"6252001","countryName":"United States","adminCode1":"NC","fclName":"city, village,...","countryCode":"US","lng":"-76.98661","fcodeName":"populated place","toponymName":"Riverdale","distance":"1.30053","fcl":"P","name":"Riverdale","fcode":"PPL","geonameId":4488145,"lat":"34.99599","adminName1":"North Carolina","population":0}]}`

Here is the error:

`org.json.JSONException: No value for countryName`

Comment: Please post the JSON string in order for us to be able to tell if there is any countryName key. If there isn't... the exception is just what it is.

Comment: @Lupinity please check edit

Comment: What happens if you do response.getString("geonames")?

Comment: Firstly you should get root of json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your field is inside an array structure, so your getString on first level does not work.

You need to do something like (untested):

```
JSONArray geonames = response.getJSONArray("geonames");
for(int i = 0 ; i < geonames.length() ; i++){
    JSONObject geo = (JSONObject)geonames.get(i);
    String countryName = geo.getString("countryName");

    // Do something with it
}
```